# session.getCurrentProject() returns null - Maven extensions

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-extension

I'm trying to write a maven extension to calculate the duration of each build session. Here is my extension :

```
  @Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true )
  private MavenProject project;

  @Component(role = AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant.class)
  public class BuildTimeLogger extends AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant {

  public void afterSessionStart(MavenSession session) throws MavenExecutionException {

      System.out.println("${project}: "+project);
      System.out.println("Top level project:"+session.getTopLevelProject());
 System.out.println("session.getcurrentproject():"+session.getCurrentProject());       }  
    }
```

I'm not sure why all the above print statements print `null`.  Am I using the session object properly? My understanding is that Maven is supposed to send all the session details of the project being built. I tried this on different projects but doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: not sure what is wrong here, but you might want to check [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4639?focusedCommentId=14421259&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14421259)

Comment: What about https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-buildtime-profiler and LifeCycleParticipant is not the best way to solve this, cause an EventSpy is a better approach...Furthermore the LifeCycleParticipant can only work correct with Maven 3.2.5+ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this some more and figured that it does print these details when printed from `afterProjectsRead()` instead.

Pasting from official documentation:

> afterSessionStart - Invoked after MavenSession instance has been
>   created. This callback is intended to allow extensions to inject
>   execution properties, activate profiles and perform similar tasks that
>   affect MavenProject instance construction.
>
> afterProjectsRead - Invoked after all MavenProject instances have been
>   created. This callback is intended to allow extensions to manipulate
>   MavenProjects before they are sorted and actual build execution
>   starts.

So I think the MavenProject instance is not created yet at afterSessionStart().
Think it could definitely be more descriptive :-/